# SSL icon [https secure] dissappears after refreshing page

Tags: ssl, https

When I first time enter my website, then I have SSL secure icon in Chrome.

But when I refresh the page, it is showing Not Secure on the same page.

How is it possible?

I don't have any http: links in my website.

Only thing I was thinking about is I have .php extension in my files. Is it related?

Example: https://mywebsitetest.com/dashboard.php [SECURE FIRST TIME VISIT]
Refreshing the page goes to http: http://mywebsitetest.com/dashboard.php [NOT SECURE AFTER REFRESHING]

Comment: What server are you using? How is it configured?

Comment: I'm not sure about all configuration, I have LAMP on DigitalOcean Ubuntu 18.04